# timeGetTime() start variable is bigger than end variable

Tags: c++, windows, ogre

I am using `timeGetTime()` to limit the framerate to 60 frames per second. The way i intend to do that is get the time it takes to render said 60 frames and then use Sleep to wait the remainder of the second. But for some reason `timeGetTime()` is returning a way bigger number the first time i call it than when i call it after the 60 frames are rendered.

Here is the code:

Header

```
#ifndef __TesteMapa_h_
#define __TesteMapa_h_
#include "BaseApplication.h"
#include "Mundo.h"

class TesteMapa : public BaseApplication{
public:
    TesteMapa()
    virtual ~TesteMapa();

protected:
    virtual void createScene();

    virtual bool frameRenderingQueued(const Ogre::FrameEvent& evt);
    virtual bool frameEnded(const Ogre::FrameEvent& evt);

    virtual bool keyPressed(const OIS::KeyEvent &evt);
    virtual bool keyReleased(const OIS::KeyEvent &evt);

private:
    Mundo mundo = Mundo(3,3,3);
    short altura, largura, passos, balanca, framesNoSegundo=0;
    Ogre::SceneNode *noSol, *noSolFilho, *noCamera;
    DWORD inicioSegundo = 0, finala;//inicioSegundo is the start variable and finala the ending variable
};
#endif
```

CPP relevant function

```
bool TesteMapa::frameEnded(const Ogre::FrameEvent& evt){
    framesNoSegundo++;

    if (inicioSegundo == 0)
        inicioSegundo = timeGetTime();
    else{
        if (framesNoSegundo == 60){
            finala = timeGetTime(); //getting this just to see the value being returned
            Sleep(1000UL - (timeGetTime() - inicioSegundo));
            inicioSegundo = 0;
            framesNoSegundo = 0;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am using `timeBeginPeriod(1)` and `timeEndPeriod(1)` in the main function.

Comment: Hmm, no, it is never a bug in the operating system.  That Sleep() call is pretty borken.  It is going to sleep for a very long time when 60 frames took a bit more than a second.  They usually do.

Comment: "60 frames" isn't a frame rate. I'm confused as to what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure it returns 'a way bigger value'? I mean if your 60 frames take more than 1000ms, you will end up sleeping basically forever because you are using unsigned types. Apart from this being a weird way of limiting the framerate, I'd use `std::chrono::steady_clock` instead of windows-specific functions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I will edit it.

Comment: @Rostislav When i put a break point in the Sleep line inicioSegundo==747473412 and finala=6361192. I will check if it took more time. Thank you.

Comment: @Rostislav Could you tell me what are the perks of using std::chrono?

Comment: First, it's a part of the standard and it's cross-platform. Second, (and more importantly in your case I guess) it has specific types for representing times and durations (`std::chrono::time_point` and `std::chrono::duration` as opposed to generic `DWORD`) which minimize the potential mistakes that one could make writing the code related to time measurements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio 2013 or older, std::chrono uses the 64hz ticker (15.625 ms per tick), which is slow. VS 2015 is supposed to fix this. You can use QueryPerformanceCounter instead. Here is example code that runs at a fixed frequency with no drift, since delays are based off an original reading of the counter. dwLateStep is a debugging aid that gets incremented if one or more steps took too long. The code is Windows XP compatible, where Sleep(1) can take up to 2 ms, which is why the code only does a sleep if there is 2 ms or more of time to delay.

```
typedef unsigned long long UI64;        /* unsigned 64 bit int */
#define FREQ    60                      /* frequency */
DWORD    dwLateStep;                    /* late step count */
LARGE_INTEGER liPerfFreq;               /* 64 bit frequency */
LARGE_INTEGER liPerfTemp;               /* used for query */
UI64 uFreq = FREQ;                      /* thread frequency */
UI64 uOrig;                             /* original tick */
UI64 uWait;                             /* tick rate / freq */
UI64 uRem = 0;                          /* tick rate % freq */
UI64 uPrev;                             /* previous tick based on original tick */
UI64 uDelta;                            /* current tick - previous */
UI64 u2ms;                              /* 2ms of ticks */
UI64 i;

    /* ... */ /* wait for some event to start thread */
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&liPerfFreq);
    u2ms = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart)+499) / ((UI64)500);

    timeBeginPeriod(1);                 /* set period to 1ms */
    Sleep(128);                         /* wait for it to stabilize */

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&liPerfTemp);
    uOrig = uPrev = liPerfTemp.QuadPart;

    for(i = 0; i < (uFreq*30); i++){
        /* update uWait and uRem based on uRem */
        uWait = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart) + uRem) / uFreq;
        uRem  = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart) + uRem) % uFreq;
        /* wait for uWait ticks */
        while(1){
            QueryPerformanceCounter((PLARGE_INTEGER)&liPerfTemp);
            uDelta = (UI64)(liPerfTemp.QuadPart - uPrev);
            if(uDelta >= uWait)
                break;
            if((uWait - uDelta) > u2ms)
                Sleep(1);
        }
        if(uDelta >= (uWait*2))
            dwLateStep += 1;
        uPrev += uWait;
        /* fixed frequency code goes here */
        /*  along with some type of break when done */
    }

    timeEndPeriod(1);                   /* restore period */
```

Comment: Thank you. I am indeed using VS2013. I will try the QueryPerformanceCounter approach.

Answer (score 2):

Without even reading the complete question, the following:

> using timeGetTime()
>   t limit the framerate to 60 frames per second
>   ...
>   Sleep for the remainder of the second

can be answered with a firm "You are doing it wrong". In other words, stop here, and take a different approach.

Neither does `timeGetTime` have the necessary precision (not even if you use `timeBeginPeriod(1)`), nor does `Sleep` have the required precision, nor does `Sleep` give any guarantees about the maximum duration, nor are the semantics of `Sleep` even remotely close to what you expect, nor is sleeping to limit the frame rate a correct approach.
Also, calculating the remainder of the second will inevitably introduce a systematic error that will accumulate over time.

The one and only correct approach to limit frame rate is to use vertical sync.

If you need to otherwise limit a simulation to a particular rate, using a waitable timer is the correct approach. That will still be subject to the scheduler's precision, but it will avoid accumulating systematic errors, and priority boost will *at least* give a de-facto soft realtime guarantee.

In order to understand why what you are doing is (aside from precision and accumulating errors) conceptually wrong to begin with, consider two things:

1. Different timers, even if they run at apparently the same frequency, will diverge (thus, using any timer other than the vsync interrupt is *wrong* to limit frame rate). Watch cars at a red traffic light for a real-life analogy. Their blinkers will *always* be out of sync.
2. `Sleep` makes the current thread "not ready" to run, and eventually, some time after the specified time has passed, makes the thread "ready" again. That doesn't mean that the thread will run at that time again. Indeed, it doesn't necessarily mean that the thread will run at all in any finite amount of time.
3. Resolution is commonly around 16ms (1ms if you adjust the scheduler's granularity, which is an antipattern -- some recent architectures support 0.5ms by using the undocumented Nt API), which is way too coarse for something on the 1/60 second scale.

Comment: The problem with this answer is that i want to limit the game to 60 fps and the game will run at higher values if the refresh rate of the monitor is higher. But yeah, i my approach was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You can run the logic at 60Hz nevertheless (indeed, for any such thing as integration, a fixed time step is desirable, virtually essential) and interpolate what you present on the screen. But what you present still has to be synced with the correct timer (vsync interrupt), not with anything else. Plus, you probably want to have a 6Hz timer and run the logis for 10 frames at a time, rather than a 60Hz timer, due to the limited precision of the scheduler. Or better yet, no timer at all, but a producer that provides states as needed (consumed by the render thread that uses vsync).

Comment: You can for example always render one fixed time snapshot into the future and interpolate between this and the last (for example 1/10 second) and whenever the interpolation reaches the once-future-now-present state, you signal the producer to generate another snapshot (which you will then use from the next frame onwards to interpolate to).